# How can I log messages in content script of firefox extension?

Tags: debugging, logging, firefox, content-script

I am new to Firefox extension (add-on) development. I'm injecting a content script through my sidebar code-behind using the `browser.tabs.executeScript()` API. And I run my extension using `web-ext run` command.

The problem is, my log doesn't appear in developer console and when I go to tools console, I can see the following error:

```
Error: Missing host permission for the tab
```

Mozilla defines a [*host permission*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#host_permissions) as given through pattern matching of page URL. And of course adding the following to my `manifest.json` file fixes the issue:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ]
```

But I'd like to inject the content script on demand, not based on the page URL.

Another way is to send messages through API to my sidebar code-behind and then log it there in my extension console. But this requires a bit of implementation. On the other hand, It makes me wondering **why shouldn't I be able to simply log a message to developer console through an injected script?**

This is my code:

`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":"My Extension",
    "version":"1.0",
    "sidebar_action":{
        "default_title": "My sidebar",
        "default_panel": "sidebar/panel.html"
    },
    "permissions":[]
}
```

`panel.js`:

```
browser.tabs.executeScript({ file: "content-script.js" });
```

`content-script.js`:

```
console.log('first line of content script');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The term `<all_urls>` can be used as a permission:

```
"permissions":["<all_urls>"]
```

Then `console.log()` works within content script.

However, it is not recommended to include this permission: [Avoid host permission "<all_urls>" if you can](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/request-the-right-permissions/#avoid-unnecessary-permissions)